# Use poetry to create templated Python projects

Tags: python, python-poetry, package-management

Having struggled with Python package management, I have come to like [Poetry](https://python-poetry.org/). I am (mostly) able to use it without issues and installing packages is working well for me.

However, I find myself repeating the same pattern over and over again:

```
poetry new my_new_package
cd my_new_package
poetry add numpy pandas matplotlib rich ipython black scikit-learn scipy mypy
rm README.rst
touch README.md
git init
```

I.e., there are a few packages  that I always want installed, I always want to run `git init`, and I prefer the `.md` readme over the `.rst` one.

Oh, and I also change `python = "^3.10"` to `python = "~3.10"` in the `pyproject.toml`.

My wish is that I can do something like `poetry from template pyproject.toml` instead of all of the above. Now I get that, if I just run `poetry install pyproject.toml` with the `pyproject.toml` file from above, `poetry` would install all packages. But it would not create the folder structure, the readme, the git folders, etc.

**Question:** Is there a way to achieve what I want? Ideally, I could also have a dynamic project name, e.g. `poetry from template pyproject.toml my_other_project`. Is this possible with `poetry`? Or am I just using the wrong tool?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This kind of flexibility is out of scope for Poetry. Use [cookiecutter](https://github.com/cookiecutter/cookiecutter) instead.

Comment: Or [_`copier`_](https://pypi.org/project/copier/) or any other tool like that

Answer (score 0):

If you are on Windows, a cmd file like the one below can be used:

Fixing up python = "^3.10" to python = "~3.10" in the pyproject.toml.
is left as an exercise for the student. :)

Hint: sed or awk can be used for this sort of thing.

Note: Script ignores any arguments after the 1st one.

### poetry_new.cmd:

```
@ECHO OFF
REM creates project with my customizations
REM handles absolute and relative paths properly

SETLOCAL EnableExtensions EnableDelayedExpansion

REM if !1 arg show usage
@IF {%1} == {} goto :Usage
@IF NOT {%2} == {} goto :Usage

SET PARENT=%~dp1
SET PROJECT=%~nx1
REM PARENT=%PARENT%, PROJECT=%PROJECT%

IF NOT EXIST "%PARENT%" (
    MKDIR "%PARENT% "
    if ERRORLEVEL 1 Goto :FAIL MKDIR %1 -- failed
)

PUSHD "%PARENT%"

poetry new "%PROJECT%"

PUSHD "%PROJECT%"

poetry remove pytest -D

REM add more customizations here:
REM poetry add pytest
REM poetry add numpy pandas matplotlib rich ipython black scikit-learn scipy mypy

RENAME README.rst README.md

REM Post poetry new
REM open explorer in newly created project folder
start /B Explorer /n,/e,.

start PyCharm "%1"

goto :EOF

:Usage
    SET ERRORLEVEL=99
    @ECHO Usage %0 new-project-name ... - creates project with my customizations
    goto :Fail Usage %0 new-project-name ... - creates project with my customizations

:Fail
@ECHO %*
PAUSE
EXIT
```